# use package flutter_pdfview But when using the PDFViewer and PDFDocument commands it is not possible

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pdf

use package flutter_pdfview But when using the PDFViewer and PDFDocument commands it is not possible.

i use this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview
`flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.7`

my file code error

```
//this is order_detail.dart

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/model/orders.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';

class OrderDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Orders order;

  OrderDetailScreen({required this.order});

  Future<void> _viewPDF(BuildContext context, String filePath) async {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PDFViewer(
          document: PDFDocument.file(
            File(filePath), // Use PDFDocument.file to open from a file path
            // Set configuration options here if needed
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Order Details"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Recipient Name: ${order.recipientName}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                "Printing Type: ${order.printingType}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                "Number of Sets: ${order.numberOfSets}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                "Phone Number: ${order.phoneNumber}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                "Pickup Location: ${order.pickupLocation}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                "Pickup Time: ${order.pickupTime}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                "Additional Details: ${order.additionalDetails}",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(
                "Documents:",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              if (order.documents.isNotEmpty)
                Column(
                  children: order.documents
                      .map(
                        (document) => GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            // Open and view the document when tapped
                            _viewPDF(context, document);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            document
                                .split('/')
                                .last, // Display only the document's filename
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(
                "Transfer Slips:",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              if (order.transferSlips.isNotEmpty)
                Column(
                  children: order.transferSlips
                      .map((transferSlip) => Image.file(
                            File(transferSlip),
                            width: 200,
                            height: 200,
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

error line 17 : have red line in PDFViewer
error line 18 : have red line in PDFDocument
Unused import: 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart'.
Try removing the import directive.
how to fix it?

i find how to fix code